# php - how to merge key with subkey in one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like that :

```
array(
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 3 => 'value',
        (int) 12 => 'value'
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        (int) 8 => 'value',
        (int) 10 => 'value',
        (int) 15 => 'value'
    )
)
```

What is the best way to merge the keys with the subkeys without taking into consideration values, to get something like that ?

```
array(
    (int) 0 => (int) 1,
    (int) 1 => (int) 3,
    (int) 2 => (int) 12,
    (int) 3 => (int) 5,
    (int) 4 => (int) 8,
    (int) 5 => (int) 10,
    (int) 6 => (int) 15
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short solution using `array_keys` and `array_merge` functions:

```
$keys = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {  // $arr is your initial array
    $keys[] = $k;
    if (is_array($v)) $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($v));
}

print_r($keys);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 15
)
```

Comment: What is $v, what is $k, in context these make sense - but why the need to sacrifice readability to save a few characters?

Comment: are you searching for "characters" or for working solutions?

Comment: I'm just asking for justification @RomanPerekhrest - seems unnecessary is all, just reduces code readability.

Comment: *seems unnecessary is all* - does all seem unnecessary for you? it seems that it's just your opinion

Comment: Well, I just believe that providing readable code is better than providing less readable code simply to save characters, especially if the code is not self-explanatory to begin with.

Comment: so, your answer would be the most successful in such case, right?

Comment: No, @RomanPerekhrest, your answer is a much more efficient approach and avoids a double iteration, however it could be more readable is all.

Comment: Thx for u anwser, i'll used your method

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = [];

$arrays = array(
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 3 => 'value',
        (int) 12 => 'value'
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        (int) 8 => 'value',
        (int) 10 => 'value',
        (int) 15 => 'value'
    )
)

foreach($arrays as $key => $array) {
    $newArray[] = $key;
    foreach($array as $key => $item) {
        $newArray[] = $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: _Just a note:_ Jack, you can delete an answer, then edit it, then undelete the answer. Rather than deleting an answer and then creating another

Comment: Yep, my bad @RiggsFolly

Comment: Not bad, just thought I would let you know

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) for php 5 and above.

```
//$oldArray = your array
$newArray = [];

function build_array($item,$key){

    global $newArray;

    $newArray[] = $key;

}
array_walk_recursive($oldArray,'build_array');
$newArray = array_merge(array_keys($oldArray),$newArray); //needed for the first keys (1,5) as Jory Geerts correctly pointed out.
```

Comment: Using globals can make code very brittle, so we should avoid that if possible. In this case you could use a closure, like so: `array_walk_recursive($oldArray, function ($item, $key) use ($newArray) { $newArray[] = $key;});` However, as per the manual, "Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function." so this approach would not work since Carilboue wants 1 and 5 in the array as well.